# Wireshark Lua - Is It Possible to Dissect on Scroll?

Tags: lua, wireshark

I have a custom wireshark dissector, but it takes a very long time to load/dissect large captures.

Is it possible to only dissect packets when they are displayed/on scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not.  The Wireshark core has no idea whether a given dissector constructs, for some or all packets, state needed for dissecting later packets, so it has to dissect *every* packet when it reads the file in.